# How can I scale model with 4 decimal digit in ARKit/SceneKit?

Tags: augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I have a model with length as 182.925 meter I want to scale it to .0182 meter in ARKit. In the editor I cannot pass more than 3 decimal digit.

[image]

I want .0001 or similar in the scale.x field.

Answer (score 0):

In ARKit, SceneKit and RealityKit a distance from objects and size of objects are measured in **meters**. I suppose it's quite logical that the smallest size here is `mm` (10th of centimetre). So, 1 mm precision is more than enough for AR and VR models.

If you need to downscale your model you'll get the following value:

```
0.018 m   or   18 mm            // in your case
```

You can't work with `micrometer` or `nanometer` precision in RealityKit and SceneKit because it 100% would cause issues and artifacts on rendered surfaces of shaders, and there would be unnecessary computations of light rays at such a microscopic scale.

Comment: The free 3d model I downloaded is having bounding box of 182 m (X) and I want to scale it to  1.8 cm.  that's why i need .0001 in scale

Comment: Ok, you just need use 0.018, isn't it? It's precisely 18 mm or 1.8 cm.

Comment: As per my understanding if I pass .018 in scale, the actual size of the object would be 0.018*182(Bounding box width). Am I wrong with this understanding?

Comment: Nope, it'll be just 0.018. There would be complicated math if we must multiply it on BBox. Scale is explicit operation.